# jQuery slideToggle next container with class name

Tags: jquery, button, find

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/bmdpamhy/

It's three btns with content div's below. The button and content containers have class names.

The content div's are hidden.

I want to open just the content div below the button clicked.

How do I open just the div below the buton clicked.

```
        /* This will open all content divs
        $(function(){
            $('.open').click(function(){
                $('.content').slideToggle();
            });
        })
        */


        // I want to open just the content below the button clicked
        $(function(){
            $('.open').click(function(){
                $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
            });
        })
```

Comment: you're trying to toggle the next element of the button, but it is enclosed in the parent div. so you need to step out to parent and then call next `  $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect selector. `.content` is sibling of clicked buttons parent.Use:

```
$('.open').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4tdzeowb/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is some modifications in case needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/bmdpamhy/1/

This will give your slide contents a feel  of 'show-one-at-the-time'. Take a look.

```
$(function(){
    $('.open').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();

               $(this).parents('.wrap').find('.content.opened').slideToggle().toggleClass('opened'); 
$(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle().toggleClass('opened');

    });
})
```